# Placing images in textBox

Tags: xaml

How can I place images in a XAML TEXTBOX?
I am looking for a control that I could place an image and a text next to it and it have to be
scrollable.

Answer (score 1):

Use a [RichTextBox](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.richtextbox.aspx). It provides functionality to display Text and Images.